# I am having an issue with paypal plugin with woocommerce . I get an error message which says"semantically incorrect , business validation failed

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, semantic-ui

How do I rectify paypal payment error in woocommerce set up on wordpress. I get error message as invalid business validation, semantically incorrect, currency converter error. I have changed the primary currency to Indian rupee. Have maintained the same business email account in both the settings.

Answer (score 2):

You should always include the full error message response in you question.. but in this case:

> I have changed the primary currency to Indian rupee.

PayPal [does not support](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/location/india/) Indian rupees, nor domestic Indian transactions. Only international transactions are supported. (where one of the parties is *not* from India and the currency is *not* rupees)

Comment: Its all in the manual.